# How to encode url in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, url

**EDIT (Side Question)**

Can someone please explain what this line does?

```
eval website=\${$#}
```

The script reads a lot of paremeters, it's called somewhat like this

./script.sh -t 30 -n 100 -a test http://www.google.com

I have trouble reading the url ( http://www.google.com )

---

I am opening firefox using urls passed to a bash script. How do I encode them? Some of these urls are causing issue.

Some code

```
eval website=\${$#} // takes as argument

firefox -width 1280 -height 8000 ${website} &
```

Problematic URL

http://www.airportbusiness.com//print/Airport-Business-Magazine/Expo-Returns-to-Vegas/1$41912

In firefox, it opens as

http://www.airportbusiness.com//print/Airport-Business-Magazine/Expo-Returns-to-Vegas/141912

$ sign gets removed

Comment: please include the problematic url to make the illustration/testing easier

Comment: -1 : this question has very little to do with URL encoding and a lot to do with bash quoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to escape the characters that cause some problems.

Unless your url contain some unusual characters as `'`, or `\`, you should be fine just by putting your url between tow `'`:

```
$ firefox 'YOUR_URL'
```

This will prevent `YOUR_URL` content to be evaluated.

---

**Edit**, to reflect updated answer:

You can see using `echo` command how bash expands your parameters.

In your example, bash thinks `$` is used to identify a variable (a variable named `4`), thus it substitutes `$4` with the value of variable `4`, which is not defined (thus just removes `$4`):

```
$ echo http://www.airportbusiness.com//print/Airport-Business-Magazine/Expo-Returns-to-Vegas/1$41912
http://www.airportbusiness.com//print/Airport-Business-Magazine/Expo-Returns-to-Vegas/11912
$ echo 'http://www.airportbusiness.com//print/Airport-Business-Magazine/Expo-Returns-to-Vegas/1$41912'
http://www.airportbusiness.com//print/Airport-Business-Magazine/Expo-Returns-to-Vegas/1$41912
```

Answer (score 2):

Never use `eval`, and always quote your variables. The first argument ist stored in the parameter `1`:

```
firefox "$1" &
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
eval website=\${$#}
```

sets the variable to the last positional parameter, regardless of how many there are.

Change it to:

```
website=${@: -1}
```

which is a Bashism, by the way.

Here are a few other Bashisms that accomplish the same thing:

```
echo "${!#}"
echo "${@:$#}"
echo "${BASH_ARGV[0]}"
```